# Mobile Template - ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I added dynamic map service to [the mobile template](http://www.arcgis.com/sharing/content/items/194a24ac15c64ca38916f2ce4f68c306/data) from ESRI.
However, I see a couple of issues:

1. map does not cover full screen (when vertical).
2. background shows black on mobile browser (chrome).

Here is [a site](http://gis.wiu.edu/java/mobile/).

Answer (score 1):

Black background issue: seems like your dojo deviceTheme CSS is broken when it detects Android. If you do the following, you'll see the black background goes away:

http://gis.wiu.edu/java/mobile/?theme=iPhone

You can see how this works at [Dojo site](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.html).

Not filling up the screen issue: Your map div is called `mapDiv`, but in your code, it's trying to resize a div called `map`. Just reconcile the two and you should be good, i think!